# How do I make the output printed in separate lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

i have this code

```
import random
sen_1 = input("pls enter the sent 1: ") 
sen_2 = input("pls enter the sent 2: ")
sen_3 = input("pls enter the sent 3: ")
sen_4 = input("pls enter the sent 4: ")

sent = [sen_1 , sen_2 , sen_3 , sen_4]
random.shuffle(sent)
print(sent)
```

instead of `["x", "x", "x", "x"]`

Im expecting an output like this:

```
["x", 

 "x",

 "x",

 "x"]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain the exact output as you described, I would first call the **str**() method then replace the "," with a ",\n" (comma-separator and a line-break), like so

```
print(str(sent).replace("," , ",\n"))
```

So your print output will look exactly like this:

```
['x',
 'x',
 'x',
 'x']
```

Comment: `sent.__str__()` refers to a special method, `str(sent)` should be used instead

Comment: yes, you are right, just edited the answer accordingly, thanks

Comment: Relying on the output of the lists representation (that is mostly meant for debugging purposes) isn't something I would do.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use this:

```
print(*sent, sep = "\n")
```

Finally, it will look like that:

```
import random
sen_1 = input("pls enter the sent 1: ") 
sen_2 = input("pls enter the sent 2: ")
sen_3 = input("pls enter the sent 3: ")
sen_4 = input("pls enter the sent 4: ")

sent = [sen_1 , sen_2 , sen_3 , sen_4]
random.shuffle(sent)
print(*sent, sep = "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop your array like this:

```py
for element in sent:
    print(element)
```

Comment: I tried this but for some reason, it didn't work

Comment: my bad, I had missed " : "

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply join the contents of the list with the newline character

```
print('\n'.join(sent))
```